# C# GhostScript convert multiple PDFs to PostScript

Tags: c#, pdf, ghostscript, postscript

Can anyone suggest how to merge multiple PDF files into a single PostScript file when using GhostScript with C#

Using the command line works and merges the two input PDF files to a single PostScriptFile:

```
gswin32c.exe -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOutputFile=outfile.ps Infile1.pdf Infile2.pdf
```

I cannot get it to work in C# though:

```
params.Add("-q");
params.Add("-dQUIET");
params.Add("-dNOPAUSE");
params.Add("-dBATCH");
params.Add("-P-");
params.Add("-dPARANOIDSAFER");
params.Add("-dNOPROMPT");
params.Add("-sDEVICE=ps2write");
params.Add("-dLanguageLevel=3);
params.Add("-dASCII85DecodePages=false");
params.Add("-sOutputFile=outfile.ps");
params.Add("InFile1.PDF inFile2.PDF");
```

I did try it with a comma between the output file names as well.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, Mike

Comment: Where do you pass 'params' to ? Also, in your command line I don't see -p switch like in the C# code.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with something like this:

```
params.Add("-ignored");
params.Add("-q");
params.Add("-dQUIET");
params.Add("-dNOPAUSE");
params.Add("-dBATCH");
params.Add("-dPARANOIDSAFER");
params.Add("-dNOPROMPT");
params.Add("-sDEVICE=ps2write");
params.Add("-dLanguageLevel=3");
params.Add("-dASCII85DecodePages=false");
params.Add("-sOutputFile=outfile.ps");
params.Add("-f");
params.Add("C:\fullpath\InFile1.PDF");
params.Add("C:\fullpath\inFile2.PDF");
```

Comment: Note that -o implies -dBATCH and -dNOPAUSE so you can get the same effect in a shorter command line by setting "-o outfile.ps". In both cases you don't need -dNOPROMPT. Unless you are piping into GS I would not suggest using -dNOPROMPT. If you set -q you don't need -dQUIET (and when debugging a problem I would not set either!). PARANOIDSAFER is just the same as SAFER and we'd rather you used SAFER, PARANOIDSAFER is no longer documented and may be removed (although after 12 years...). -dLanguageLevel=3 has no effect on ps2write, because ps2write writes language level **2**, hence the name...

Comment: Also, -dASCII85DecodePages isn't valid, Presumably you mean ASCII85EncodePages

Comment: Thanks for the tips Ken. Always want to go for best practices.